# Add field from one event type to another event type

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have 3 types of events in a Kafka stream:

```
{etype: A, eid: 101, name: Max, my_id:30001}

{etype:B, eid: 101, age:21, my_id:30001}
{etype:C, eid: 101, car:honda, my_id:30005}
```

All these events are flowing in same topic.
I want to end up with the following egress topic:

```
{etype: A, eid: 101, name: Max, my_id:30001}

{etype:B, eid: 101, name: Max, age:21, my_id:30001}
{etype:C, eid: 101, name: Max, car:honda, my_id:30005}
```

Basically the "name" is in one type of event and I want to get the name in all the other events.
I am new to Flink, but it seems it would be a good starting point for more complex processing.
How can I do the above in Java?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider creating a pipeline that would be keyed by something that relates to the name that you care about (e.g. `eid`). This would ensure that all of the events flowing in that shared that identifier would be routed through the same stateful process function (i.e. [`KeyedProcessFunction`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/process_function/)).

Using a stateful function will allow you to store important state information for everything that shares that same `eid` (i.e. `KeyedState`) and you could perform some rudimentary enrichment as demonstrated below (with a simple example using some generic `JsonObject` but you could replace this with your own class):

```
// Function that accepts incoming keyed (strings) events 
// (JsonObject) and outputs enriched events (JsonObject)
class EventEnrichmentFunction: KeyedProcessFunction<String, JsonObject, JsonObject>() {

    // Define the state (mapping properties as key-value pairs of strings)
    private lateinit var state: MapState<String, String>

    override fun open(parameters: Configuration) {
        // Initialize the state (just a map of key-value string pairs)
        state = runtimeContext.getMapState(
            MapStateDescriptor("events", TypeInformation.of(String::class.java), TypeInformation.of(String::class.java))
        )
    }

    // Function that accepts an incoming event (JsonObject), 
    // enriches against state, and outputs events (JsonObject)
    override fun processElement(event: JsonObject, ctx: Context, collector: Collector<JsonObject>) {
        if (state.isEmpty) {
            // This is the first time we've seen an event 
            //with this id, so we need to add properties to keep
            // track of what we've seen
            state.put("name", event.name)
        }

        // Check for properties that you want to try and enrich
        if (!event.has("name") && state.containsKey("name")) {
            event.addProperty("name", state.get("name"))
        }

        // Return the enriched event
        collector.collect(event)
    }
}
```

Basically, any keyed stateful function will allow you to retain information based on a specific key (in this case the `eid`) so that future events sharing that same key can access the state of those preceding it, continuing to build the future matching events up over time:

```
if (state.isEmpty) {
    // This is the first time we've seen an event with this id, 
    // so we need to add properties to keep track of what we've seen
    state.put("name", event.name)
    state.put("another_property", event.another_property)
    state.put("yet_another_one", event.yet_another_one);

}

// TODO: Add checks and conditionally enrich events as needed from state
```

Which might looks something like this when defining your job itself:

```
events
   .keyBy { e -> e.get("eid") }
   .process(EventEnrichmentFunction())
   .sinkTo(...)
```